# Multiple state changes from multiple effect hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I can't seem to find a good pattern for one scenario...

Lets say we have this kind of order in component:

```
const component = ({propslist}) => {
const [state1, changeState1] = useState();
const [state2, changeState2] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  //this effect does something and updates state 1
  const someVar = someOperation();
  changeState1(someVar);
});

useEffect(() => {
  //this effect does something and updates state 2
  const someVar = someOtherOperation();
  changeState2(someVar);
});

return (<div>...</div>);
}
```

Now, if i understand correctly and from what i see in my tests, the moment first `useEffect` changes the state, the component will re-render.
The thing that makes me think so is that if i put it that way i get error: `Rendered fewer hooks than expected`.

2 questions:

1. Is it the case that the moment something changes the state that component stops execution and goes into re-render?
2. How to change multiple states from multiple effects? Is there some good pattern about it? Should we have remodel things to pack all state changes into single effects hook or pack all 'chunks' into single state monolith object and change it from single place?

Any suggestions & best practices would be appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**

My apologies.

I was testing different versions and posted wrong code example.
This is the code example that causes error `Rendered fewer hooks than expected.`:

```
const component = ({propslist}) => {
const [state1, changeState1] = useState();
const [state2, changeState2] = useState();

if(someCondition)
  changeState1(something);

useEffect(() => {
  //this effect does something and updates state 2
  const someVar = someOperation();
  changeState2(someVar);
});

return (<div>...</div>);
}
```

So, i guess call to `changeState1()` starts re-render immediately and prevents `useEffect` from being called thus causing the error. Right?

Comment: What are you referring to with "if i put it that way"?

Comment: if i try the flow described in a code "example". so, if i do things in that order and that way.

Comment: The code you have there shouldn't cause that error. Can you make a codesandbox?

Comment: @Colin i've messed a few things up. Please take a look at my updated post. tnx

Comment: For the second code, you need to have your `useEffect` hooks *after* the condition.

Comment: @Colin yes yes, i just did a lot of testing and mixed up which particular version produced an error. please post it as answer so i can accept it. tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the "Rendered fewer hooks than expected" error, you need to put your `useEffect` hooks **after** the `if` statement.